# store 32 bit int into a char buffer

Tags: c, udp, char, int

I'm working with a UDP program which collects data to be sent into a char array, but the data I need to send is a 32 bit int. How can I send this data?

Comment: In what language? Do you have code? In C, integers can safely be converted to a char (byte) array representation. You'd just have to translate it to network byte order first.

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified - yes, it's in C. I don't have any code yet, and what code I do have is irrelevant to this subject so that won't help... I can say this though, I'm using the NetBurner development kit and they have a built in OS that allows you to take a char array and form a UDP packet around it. Can't be int type, only char. Since all my data is 32bits long, I'm at a loss as to how to convert it to type char. I'm a bit of a newb at this, and although I understand a few things, I have a lot to learn..

Answer (score 6):

In C, integer types (or any type for that matter) can safely be represented in a character arrays and back using pointer casts. This is guaranteed by the C standard.

In socket programming, you'll usually want to perform this operation on an integer that you previously translated to network-byte order:

```
uint32_t translated_int = htonl(original_int);
char *binary_string = (char *)&translated_int;
// binary_string now a pointer to the translated_int, represented as a char array
```

If you need a *copy* to pass it around, you can do so with `memcpy` instead:

```
char binary_string[ sizeof(translated_int) ];
memcpy(binary_string, &translated_int, sizeof translated_int);
// binary_string now a copy of translated_int, represented as a char array
```

If you want to translate it back:

```
uint32_t translated_int, original_int;
memcpy(&translated_int, binary_string, sizeof translated_int);
original_int = ntohl(translated_int);
```